# Why is it wrong to take the cube root of both sides $ (z+1)^3=z^3 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, radicals

if i take square root of both sides of the equation then the z cancel each other:

$ \sqrt[3] {(z+1)^3 }=\sqrt[3]{z^3} $

$ z+1 =z $

$ z-z+1=0$

$ 1=0 $

I thought this complex equation had no solution but it has if expand the binomial instead of taking the cube root:

$ \sqrt[3] {(z+1)^3} =\sqrt[3]{z^3} $

$ z^3+3z^2+3z+1=z^3   $

$z^3-z^3+3z^2+3z+1=0$

$3z^2+3z+1=0$

which gives us two diferent results:

$-\frac{1}{6}i(\sqrt3-3i)$  and $\frac{1}{6}i(\sqrt3+3i)$

i also checked in wolfram alpha and it seems like i did no mistake. those are the result obtained with each method

1)https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cuberoot%28%28z-1%29%5E3%29%3Dcuberoot%28z%5E3%29
2) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28z%2B1%29%5E3%3Dz%5E3

In what cases is not correct to take cube root of both sides?
i understand that this could be a problem with cube root because the square its not reversible but this is a cuberoot.

Comment: $z$ is not the only cube root of $z^{3}$. There are three complex numbers whose cube is $z^{3}$.

Comment: Regarding your comment on reversibility at the end: cube root is reversible over the real numbers, but not over the complex numbers.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* take cube roots, provided you take into account the fact that you're allowing for complex solutions.

$x^3 = 1$ has three solutions in $\mathbb C$, $x = 1, \omega, \omega^2$. These are called the three complex cube roots of unity. The latter two are non-real conjugate roots, equal to $-\frac 12 \pm i\frac {\sqrt 3} {2}$.

Taking the cube roots, we have $z+1 = z$ which does not give any solutions, or $z+1 = \omega z \implies z = \frac 1{\omega-1}$ or $z+1 = \omega^2 z \implies z = \frac 1{\omega^2-1}$ which will give you the two non-real complex conjugate roots you're looking for.

Alternatively, you could group and factor or expand to solve the resulting quadratic and get the same two complex conjugate roots.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the equation $(x+2)^2=x^2$ instead. Does this imply $x+2=x$ and therefore have no solutions? No: $x=-1$ is a solution.

The problem with just eliminating the $^2$ on both sides is that squaring is not [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function): there are different numbers with the same square, so knowing $A^2=B^2$ isn't enough to conclude $A=B$. (For example, we could have $A=1$ and $B=-1$.)

With complex numbers, it's a similar situation. For every integer $n\ge 2$, the operation $z\mapsto z^n$ is non-injective (in fact, every nonzero output value corresponds to $n$ different input values), so you can't safely just eliminate the $^n$ from both sides of an equation.

What you can do is rewrite $A^n=B^n$ as $(A/B)^n=1$ to see that $A/B$ must be one of the $n$ [$n$th roots of $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity). That is, $A=\omega^kB$ where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi}n i}$ and $k\in\{1,...,n\}$. In this sense, you *can* "take the $n$th root of both sides" of an equation, but when you do, you have to introduce this additional factor that can take $n$ different values.

Notice that when $n=2$, this gives us $\omega=e^{\pi i}=-1$, so $\omega^k\in\{-1,1\}$, so $A^2=B^2$ is equivalent to $A=\pm B$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way we can interpret the solutions of $ \ (z + 1)^3 \ = \ z^3 \ \ $ is that they are the intersections of the "surfaces" represented by the  functions on each side of the equation.  While we would recognize immediately that this equation can have no *real-valued* solutions ("The cube of what number is equal to the cube of one more than that number?"), the surface described by   $ \ z^3 \ $ must be considered in $ \ \mathbb{C}^2 \ \ , $ which has a correspondence to $ \ \mathbb{R}^4 \ \ . $  The graphs below (generated by WolframAlpha) show the two three-dimensional "slices" resulting from plotting the real and imaginary parts of $ \ w \ = \ z^3 \ \ $ against the $ \ z \ = \ a + bi \ $ plane.  (The three-fold symmetry about the vertical axes can be understood by applying the "polar form" $ \ z^3 \ = \ [ \ \rho  · (  \cos  \theta  + \ i·\sin  \theta  ) \ ]^3  \ = \ \rho^3 · [ \ \cos(3 \theta) + \ i·\sin(3 \theta) \ ] \ \ . ) \ $  The surface corresponding to $ \  (z+1)^3 \ \ $ would be similar but displaced one unit "to the left" on the $ \ a-$axis.  It is the intersections of these complex hyper-surfaces that we seek.

[image]

When we treat the equation as $ \ ( \ [a + 1] + bi \ )^3 \ = \ (a + bi)^3 \ \ , $ we obtain
$$   (a + 1)^3 \ + \ 3·(a + 1)^2·bi \ + \ 3·(a + 1)·(-b^2) \ + \ (-b^3i) $$ $$ = \ \ a^3 \ + \ 3·a^2·bi \ + \ 3·a·(-b^2) \ + \ (-b^3i) \ \ . $$
Equating the real and imaginary parts of these expressions produces
$$ a^3 \ + \ 3a^2 \ + \ 3a \ + \ 1 \ - \ 3ab^2 \ - \ 3b^2 \ \ = \ \ a^3 \ - \ 3ab^2 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ 3a^2 \  - \ 3b^2 \ + \ 3a \ + \ 1   \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , $$
$$ 3a^2b \ + \ 6ab \ + \ 3b \ - \ b^3 \ \ = \ \ 3a^2b \ - \ b^3 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ 6ab \ + \ 3b \ \ = \ \ b \ · \ (6a + 3) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$
The first of these equations can be understood as that of the "vertical" hyperbola $$ \frac{b^2}{1/12} \ - \ \frac{\left(a + \frac12 \right)^2}{1/12} \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ , $$
with its center at $ \ a \ = \ -\frac12 \ , \ b \ = \ 0 \ \ $ and its vertices at $ \   \ a \ = \ -\frac12 \ , \ b \ = \ \pm \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}} \ \ . $  The second equation represents the *union* of the "horizontal" line $ \ b \ = \ 0 \ $ and the "vertical" line $ \  a \ = \ -\frac12 \ \ . $  The intersections of these "curves" [as seen in the graph below] are then $ \ z \ = \ -\frac12 \ \pm \ i·\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}} \ = \ -\frac12 \ \pm \ i·\frac{\sqrt3}{6} \ \ , $ exactly the two roots that you found.  There are no intersections on the $ \ \mathfrak{Re}(z)-$line, indicating that our equation has no real-valued solutions.

One might well ask "Wait a minute!  The equation has third-powers of $ \ z \ \ : $ where is its *third* root?"  The equation $ \ 3z^2 + 3z + 1 \ = \ 0 \ $ that you produced shows that the original equation is actually a *quadratic* equation "in disguise": the impossibility of the equation being satisfied by any real-number can be thought of as "suppressing" the third root that the cubic equation would have.

[image]